# Android best way to update UI thread from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I released an app today and I am getting some crash reports that indicate the following:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Activity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

I have on Activity and a couple of Fragments. This error happens in one my Fragments where I have an AsyncTask:

```
private ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dial, container, false);
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    new CountryCodeTask().execute();
    return view;
}

private class CountryCodeTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        if (!dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result)
    {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (result != null) {
            Spinner countryCodeSpinner = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.country_code_spinner);
            countryCodeSpinner.setAdapter(new CountryCodeAdapter(getActivity(), result));
            countryCodeSpinner.setSelection(countryCodeSpinnerValue);
            countryCodes = result;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        return MainActivity.apiService.getCountryCodes();
    }
}
```

I am guessing this is not the best way to update the UI thread from a ASyncTask. This error happens when I use the back/home button and then restart the app (but not all the time). What am I doing wrong here?

The error happens on this line: `Spinner countryCodeSpinner = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.country_code_spinner);`

Comment: in witch line the error happens?

Comment: Spinner countryCodeSpinner = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.country_code_spinner);

Comment: Why fragment updates activity but not the activity updates itself?

Comment: The only problem is that you can exit the application before the execution of this piece of code. Just put some null checks and everything will work fine.

Comment: In general, I would declare widgets globally and assign them in onCreate. That way you only code them once per lifecycle, and don't have to worry about null references to them in situations like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong really - it's to be expected that when you navigate away from an Activity via back/home, the AsyncTask will no longer have a reference to the Activity. I would modify your code to handle this common scenario:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result)
{
    if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity != null) {
        if (result != null) {
            Spinner countryCodeSpinner = (Spinner) activity.findViewById(R.id.country_code_spinner);
            countryCodeSpinner.setAdapter(new CountryCodeAdapter(activity, result));
            countryCodeSpinner.setSelection(countryCodeSpinnerValue);
            countryCodes = result;
        } else {
            cancelTaskAndShowDialog();
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your AsyncTask finishes, after you pressed back and left the activity, `getActivity`returns `null`.

You need to add a `null` check in `onPostExecute`

```
final Activity activity = getActivity()

if (dialog =! null && dialog.isShowing()) {
    dialog.dismiss();
}

if (activity != null) {
    if (result != null) {
       Spinner countryCodeSpinner = (Spinner) activity.findViewById(R.id.country_code_spinner);
       countryCodeSpinner.setAdapter(new CountryCodeAdapter(activity, result));
       countryCodeSpinner.setSelection(countryCodeSpinnerValue);
       countryCodes = result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private ProgressDialog dialog; 
private Spinner countryCodeSpinner;
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dial, container, false); 
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity()); 
    new CountryCodeTask().execute(); 
    countryCodeSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.country_code_spinner);
    return view; 
} 

private class CountryCodeTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>>
{ 
    @Override 
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    { 
        if (!dialog.isShowing()) { 
            dialog.show(); 
        } 
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result)
    { 
        if (dialog.isShowing()) { 
            dialog.dismiss(); 
        } 

        if (result != null) {
            countryCodeSpinner.setAdapter(new CountryCodeAdapter(getActivity(), result));
            countryCodeSpinner.setSelection(countryCodeSpinnerValue);
            countryCodes = result;
        } 
    } 

    @Override 
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params)
    { 
        return MainActivity.apiService.getCountryCodes(); 
    } 
}
```